# How to transfer state to another file and use it

Tags: reactjs

**In home file**

```
        const OnSubmitFevorites = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hellow')
        const Form_data = [this.state.value.label, this.state.today_date]
        console.log('Form_data' + JSON.stringify(Form_data));
    }

    <Home Fevorites={this.OnSubmitFevorites} />
```

**This is where I want to get the Form_data and send to Fevorites file**

[image]

**UPDATE** 
[image]

**AND in app it's look like this**

```
    const App = () => (
     <div>
        <Nav />
   </div>
);
```

Comment: In nav flie but nav is not component is a only function

Comment: I need to get the state from OnsubmitFevorites from Home to Fevorit file

Comment: yse is undefined